Type-safe table API in Java
We have a big Java project on Swing
I'm sick and tired of Swing's magic constants and Objects that cause runtime errors. For one thing, column is not a parameterized type so can accept and return anything at compile time. It causes bugs that we have to band-aid all the time
I was considering creating a new API. But then figured it's likely been done already since tables are nothing fancy and Java is a mature language
Does a solid type-safe table API exist in Java (given its type erasure)?
Code samples would be welcome
